# Normal cone of $V(xz,yz) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am trying to compute the normal cone of $V(xz,yz) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$, where $\mathbb{P}^3$ is taken to have coordinates $[x:y:z:w]$.

We first work in the chart where $w\neq0$. Then we have an isomorphism
$$
R :=  (\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xz,yz) ) [X_1,X_2] / (yX_1 - xX_2) \xrightarrow{\sim} \bigoplus_{n\geq0} I^n/I^{n+1},
$$
where $I = (xz,yz)$.

I am trying to understand this space geometrically. To that end consider what this bundle (once glued with the other local descriptions) is over $X$.

1. Over the plane given by $z=0$, we have that $R|_{z=0, x \neq 0} \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,X_1,X_2]/(yX_1-xX_2)$ is the line given by $V(yX_1-xX_2)$. If $x=y=0$, this is given by $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2])\cong \mathbb{A}^2$.
2. Now what happens over the line $x=y=0,\; (z\neq0)$? I suppose we should have something like $\mathbb{C}[z,X_1,X_2]$. But that would mean that the fibre is of rank $3$?

I would appreciate any help/clarification as to where I might be wrong.

Comment: No, the fiber is rank 2 as per expectation. Because you need to be viewing it as $ (\mathbb{C}[z])[X_1,X_2] $ as only $ X_1,X_2 $ are the indeterminates. For example, at $ x=0,y=0,z=5 $, the fiber is (spec of) $ \mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2] $.

Comment: OK, then part 1. is also incorrect, no?

Comment: What do you mean? Part 1 is correct. If you're not at the origin, then the fiber is a line, again as expected.

Comment: I mean that $R|_{z=0, x \neq 0} \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,X_1,X_2]/(yX_1-xX_2)$ is false, isn't it?

Comment: How is that false? If $ x = 2, y = 1 $, then the fiber is the line $ \mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2]/(X_1 - 2X_2) $. If $ x=y=0 $, then the fiber is 2-dimensional, which is the only thing immediately not clear from the picture and intuition. Everything else is what you see from the picture.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to show that for $x=y=0$, $C_{X/\mathbb{P}^3}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_L(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_L(2)$, where $L = \{x=y=0\}$ is the line. How can one see that?

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked me why $ C_{X/\mathbb{P}^3}|_L $ is isomorphic to $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) $ where $ L $ is the line given by $ x=y=0 $. Here is the explanation.

Let $ E = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(2) $ and then $ X $ is the closed subscheme of $ \mathbb{P}^3 $ defined by the section $ (xz,yz) $ of $ E $. Therefore there exists a closed embedding of $ C_{X/\mathbb{P}^3} $ into $ E|_X $. Restricting over $ L $, this gives a closed embedding $ C_{X/\mathbb{P}^3}|_L \hookrightarrow E|_L = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) $ over $ L $. We need only check that the embedding is a bijection - a closed embedding into a reduced target, which is also a bijection, is an isomorphism.

This has almost been done in the original question. Over the patch $ w \neq 0 $, the normal cone was computed as $ \mathbb({C}[z])[X_1,X_2] $ which shows that the embedding is a bijection on $ L - [0:0:1:0] $. Over the patch $ z \neq 0 $, things are even simpler since $ X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3 $ looks like $ \mathbb{C}[x,y,w]/(x,y) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^3 $ there - so the normal cone on that patch is simply $ (\mathbb{C}[w])[X_1,X_2] $ proving that the embedding is a bijection on $ L - [0:0:0:1] $. So the embedding is an isomorphism over $ L $.